# WIX get substring from variable

Tags: wix

As part of my WIX setup project, I am updating some values in the app config for the service I am installing.  One of the attributes is a number, this is the number of the location the service is being installed at.

The location is part of the machine name, for example the machine name might be "location16server".  I am trying figure out if I can get a substring or otherwise parse the number out of the machine name so that I may use it to update the .config file.  I don't see any ways that are part of WIX, but maybe with a custom action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A custom action would be required. I'd provide caution on this though as you are tightly coupling along a machine name.  This might work well in a controlled environment but could cause major headaches down the road.  I'd look for some other artifact on the machine to determine location numbers and other configuration data.  Perhaps even move it out of the installer and into the application if possible.

Comment: Yeah, it is highly unfortunate that this it the method I have to use, unfortunately it is the goto solution at my current employer.  That being said, the environment is controlled enough that I can rely on the hostname accurately reflecting the location.

I am working on the custom action route now, it seems fairly straightforward, but overkill.  Such is life.

Comment: Be sure to write the custom action to fail the installer and log why if the location number can't be optained from the hostname.  Also see if they can use group policy and/or ADSite to convey this information.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to insert a dialog box that allows the user to enter some optional parameters for the program being installed.

Here are some examples:

http://www.merlinia.com/mdt/WiXTutorial3.msl

http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain